# Problem with set related property in designer at first time

Tags: .net, winforms, designer, propertygrid, design-time

I Develop a Form Designer, also develop some custom control that inherit from standard control like button.

Also, i have some property that related, for example user must select department first, and then select person. and after user select person, I set Text of my custom control (that inherit from button in this case). 
 Note: user can change Text property.

All thing work properly, but when i load from DB or drag and drop control to form designer, Text of controlName# set,

After override Text property and debug it, i see text set right, but after set my text, designer set text with controlName#  that this wrong.

How to solve this proplem ?

Thanks in advance
Hamid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are attributes you can apply to your properties such as `ReadOnly` that will stop the designer from setting your property too.

I cant find the link at the moment, but there is also a method of telling the forms designer that it should set properties in a certain order.

---

**Edit:**

Ok, not quite what i remembered it as, but i think something like the [ISupportInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx) interface.

Something like:

```
Public Class Test
    Implements ISupportInitalise

    private _numberOne as integer
    private _numberTwo as integer
    private _initalised as boolean

    Public Property NumberOne() as Integer
        Get
            return _numberOne
        End Get
        Set(value as Integer)

            if _initalised then
                'perform checks here'
            end if

            _numberOne = value 
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property NumberTwo() as Integer
        Get
            return _numberTwo
        End Get
        Set(value as IntegeR)
            if _initalised then
                'perform checks here'
            end if

            _numberTwo = value 
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub BeginInit Implements ISupportInitalise.BeginInit
        _initalised = false
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndInit Implements ISupportInitalise.EndInit
        _initalised = true

        'perform all checks here'
    End Sub

End Class
```

This way all your checking can be disabled until your object is fully initialised.

Comment: I can't set Readonly attribute, because user can change it, but
Exact i need this: "method of telling the forms designer that it should set properties in a certain order". Could you please find link? (also i will do)   
MANY THANKS

Comment: It might not have been a web page now that i think about it, it could have been in one of my books.

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure its in a book, I will update when I get home and can have a look in the book.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in your overriden `Text` setter whether it's being set to `controlName#` and, if it is, do nothing.